# Including jquery and highcharts library

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I created a small html file, where I can upload a *.csv file and display a chart with highcharts.
I programed it with Visual Studio 2013. When I start the page from Visual Studio every thing works fine. But when I doubleclick on the *.html file in my explorer, the chart is not displaying. 
Why is this so?

I also want to use it offline. I read about some similar problems. So I included the highcharts and jquery library, but it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

```
    <script src="../../scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../scripts/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="../../scripts/exporting.js"></script>
```

Comment: do you have any errors in your browser console?

Comment: good idea. Yes, it seems that the following function is not right:     $.each(lines, function (lineNo, line) {

Comment: I replaced the $each throug a for Loop. In Visual Studio it still works. In my browser, now the line: chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(config); is the Problem: Highcharts is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

The source path was wrong

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/highstock.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="../../scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../scripts/highstock.js"></script>
```

Thanks guys!